# Relating rows in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I need to know how to relate several rows in a table together. I'll try my best to explain.

We have a page where the client enters a list of products, description and specifications in a table. This page is managed by a CMS similar to a Rich Text editor. The layout will be something like this.

```
<h1>Toyota - TR - H1</h1>
<h2>Toyota Landcruiser - TR - H2</h2>
<h3>Toyota Landcruiser Tray - TR - H3  Description(td2) specifications(td3)</h3>
```

TR - Table Row
TD - Table Column

Now, H1 is the company name, H2 is the section and H3 is the actual product. There will be many products under a section and there can be many sections under a Company and there will be multiple Companies. The client will not be able to add classes or id's. They will just create a new row in an existing table and will dump data. I have to load content from this file in to the main site. How do i relate all the products(H3) to its parent section(H2) and parent Company(H1)? Cannot use RegEx as there is no guarantee that the product name will be prefixed with company name. The final result should be something like below. I asked the client to use H1, H2, H3 to distinguish between products, sections and company.

http://imageupload.org/?d=3E55009E1

Comment: When you say "table", are you talking about an html `<table>` element or a database table? I don't understand how you want to relate the heading elements to a "table" or what you mean by putting the text "TR" in the middle of your `<h1>`, `<h2>` and `<h3>`.

Comment: I am just conveying that the h1 is in a seperate row and so are the other heading elements. Anyway, i didn't mean to display it like that. I thought the H1 is actually going to show as a real H1 in the post. And i mean HTML tables. You can actually take a look at this link. You will get a clear idea of what i am talking about. http://boonarga.foxqa.com.au/client_data/client_data.html
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jQuery's [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).

> Description: Get all following siblings of each element up to but not
>   including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery
>   object passed.

http://jsfiddle.net/WF4mt/2/

```
//first add a class to each row containing an h1 tag so that
//we can identify blocks of rows
$('h1').each( function(index) {
    //add a class to each h1 tag
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('h1row');
});

//then for each h1 row find subsequent rows that are 'children'
$('tr.h1row').each( function(index) {
    var rows = $(this).nextUntil('tr.h1row');
    rows.addClass('y' + index);
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the effort. I just came across the same selector while browsing the jQuery API. Here is the sample of what the client page will look like. I have to get content from this page and style it in the main site. 
http://boonarga.foxqa.com.au/client_data/client_data.html
I think the above code should read var rows = $(this).closest('tr').addClass('x')

Comment: Okay, this is what I have so far. Just working on a selector to get the child rows properly. http://jsfiddle.net/WF4mt/

Comment: Hi there, just noticed something. When the each() loop runs for the first time, its adding the class name to all rows including the row with next H1 and all others. If you verify the page in jsfiddle, you will notice the class 'Y' is added to all rows. Guess there is something wrong with the selector provided for nextUntil(). Any solution?

Comment: @Sparda - yes, it wasn't finished yet. I thought you had figured it out on your own so I stopped working on it. I would be happy to take another look if you still need some help.

Comment: Sure please. I tried different ways but somehow its adding the class to all rows. certainly the selector for nextUntil() is not working as expected.

Comment: @Sparda - okay, updated my answer and put a fiddle in. pretty simple and that should do the trick

Comment: Hi, Thanks but i am still seeing the same code in the fiddle. Any chance that the fiddle URL is changed?

Comment: Are you clicking the link in my post or in my comment?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I clicked the one in the comment. I exactly did the same, except that instead of using a predefined class, i am using the h1 text as the class name. This is causing an issue because of function scope. Please take a look at the code
$('#async_load h1').each( function(index) {
    //add a class to each h1 tag
    var company = $(this).text().replace(/ +/g,'_');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass(company);
 });

 $('tr.'+company).each( function(index) {
    var rows = $(this).nextUntil('tr.'+company);
    rows.addClass(company);
 })

Comment: Those are two different functions so the company variable is out of scope. This is untested, but something like this should work. You use the data object to store the classname you want to apply. You still have to use a global class name so that you can identify table boundaries. http://jsfiddle.net/4ZLzj/1/

Comment: I figured it out. Your answers were immensely helpful. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at what you're asking and hope I get it right.

If you're doing this in jQuery,

```
$('h1')
```

will pull a list of all the h1 tags, so according to your text, that should find all the records.

If you want to process all the h1's and find their corresponding h2 and h3, it would go something like this

```
$('h1').each(function(index)
{
    var h1 = $(this);

    // since we now have the index for this h1 in the page, use it to find the h2 and h3 elements
    var h2 = $('h2:eq(' + index + ')'),
        h3 = $('h3:eq(' + index + ')');

    // now we can get the text for each item and we have our company, section and product.
    var company = h1.text(),
        section = h2.text(),
        product = h3.text();
});
```

Then you can manipulate or get the h2 and h3 as needed.

I hope that answers the question for what you're asking.

Comment: Great, but lets say the 3rd h1 has 10 h3's under it. If i understand correctly, the above code only selects the h3 which has a matching index of its closest h1. The problem is all elements are under the same level and don't have parent-child relation. In brief, i would want to add a class or id to all the rows relating to a specific company.

The logic I was thinking is to begin at a h1 and add a class to that row and all rows below it until it reaches another h1. Repeat the process for all rows. I am not sure how to stop when it reaches the next h1.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is all elements are under the same level and don't have parent-child relation. In brief, i would want to add a class or id to all the rows relating to a specific company. The logic I was thinking is to begin at a h1 and add a class to that row and all rows below it until it reaches another h1. Repeat the process for all rows.

OK, so something like the following, that selects all h1, h2 and h3 elements and loops through them, noting that the [multiple selector syntax](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) returns elements in document order:

```
function assignIds() {
   var currentH1 = 0,
       currentH2 = 0,
       currentH3 = 0;
   $("h1,h2,h3").each(function() {
      var $current = $(this);
      switch(this.tagName.toLowerCase()){
         case "h1":
            currentH1++;
            currentH2 = 0;
            currentH3 = 0;
            $current.attr("id", currentH1)
                    .data("companyId", currentH1);
            break;
         case "h2":
            currentH2++;
            currentH3 = 0;
            $current.attr("id", currentH1 + "_" + currentH2)
                    .data({"companyId" : currentH1,
                           "sectionId" : currentH2});
            break;
         case "h3":
            currentH3++;
            $current.attr("id", currentH1 + "_" + currentH2 + "_" + currentH3)
                    .data({"companyId" : currentH1,
                           "sectionId" : currentH2,
                           "productId" : currentH3});
            break;
      }
   });
);
```

The above assigns [data attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and also shows one way to generate unique ids. (For, e.g., h3 elements the id is in the form "companyId_sectionId_productId", where "2_4_9" would be the second company's fourth section's ninth product.) Obviously you can set these up differently or assign classes or whatever.